# Sharing publicly while inserting object by Google Cloud Storage JSON API

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am inserting images using Google Cloud Storage JSON API as shown in this [sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-getting-started-javascript/blob/master/index.html), that  needs to be shared publicly with read permissions. HTTP request looks like this:

```
      var request = gapi.client.request({
      'path': '/upload/storage/v1beta2/b/' + BUCKET + '/o',
      'method': 'POST',
      'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
      'headers': {'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'},
      'body': multipartRequestBody});
```

My bucket already has 'Reader' permission for 'All Users', but inserted objects don't inherit that property. Following URL throw access denied till I click on 'Share Publicly' checkbox. 
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/bucketname%2Ffilename

I need those image to be available as soon as inserted. Is there a way to share as part of HTTP insert request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a property that represents the default permissions of objects created in a bucket, but it's not the bucket permissions. Buckets have a separate property for this purpose called the "default object ACL." If you set this property to public-read, newly created objects will be publicly readable.

If you have gsutil, you can easily set this property to public read like so:

```
gsutil defacl set public-read gs://mybucket
```

Alternately, you could modify your call to explicitly set the permissions. Part of your multipart upload is presumably a JSON description of the object being created. One of those properties is "acl", which you can set however you like.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, is there no way to do this on cloud.google.com/console ?
By setting object level prop, do you mean adding following to code in the question ?
'acl':{'All':'public-read'}

Comment: Sadly, no. Canned ACLs like "public-read" are not yet supported in the JSON document. The closest you could get would be "acl" : [{'entity': 'allUsers', 'role': 'READER'}]".

Comment: Also, no, I don't believe that default object ACLs are exposed through the console, only the command line tool and the API.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, setting default ACL using gsutil command that you gave worked for me. Now all inserted files are 'public-read' by default.

Comment: Update: Predefined ACLs became available in JSON API v1. Hooray!